# How can I execute the SQL query first then the rest of the code?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

```
static listFunc() {

  let funclist = [];

  const queryList = "SELECT * FROM func";

  mysqlModule.queryDB(database, queryList, (err, result) => {
    console.log(result[0].id);

    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({
        "status_code": 500,
        "status_message": "internal server error"
      });
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        let func = {

          'id': result[i].id,
          'psw': result[i].senha,
          'nome': result[i].nome,
          'DoB': result[i].dataNascimento,
          'sexo': result[i].genero,
          'morada': result[i].morada,
          'permissoes': result[i].permissoes
        }
        funclist.push(func);
      }

      return funclist;
    }
  });
}
```

I created a function to give me all the workers from my DataBase and then store them inside `funclist` array.
The problem is the `for` loop is running before the query.
How can I run the loop only after query as finished?

Comment: I'm not really clued up on JS, but can't you use a Promise to wait for the query to return and then move onto your loop?

Comment: I do not really understand your question, I only see one query ( `mysqlModule.queryDB(database, ...`)  and the only `for` loop in your question is in the ready callback of the query. So the query should be finished at the time the `for` loop runs.

Comment: I already fix the problem i will post the anwser in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static listFunc() {

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        let funclist = [];

                mysqlModule.queryDB(database,"SELECT * FROM func", (err, result) => {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    result.forEach((result) => {
                        let func = {
                            'id': result.id,
                            'psw': result.senha,
                            'nome': result.nome,
                            'DoB': result.dataNascimento,
                            'sexo': result.genero,
                            'morada': result.morada,
                            'permissoes': result.permissoes
                        }
                        funclist.push(func);

                    });  
                    resolve(funclist);    
                });
    });
}
```

First i changed the "for" loop to  a "each" loop and i used the promise to give me the data only after i get the query and the loop finished.

```
function clistFunc(req, res){
Func.listFunc().then((data)=>{
        res.render('admin/adminListFunc', { funclist: data});
        console.log(data);
}).catch(()=>{
    console.log('Error');
});
}
```

Then i just rendered  the jade only after my listFunc() return the pretended data.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a callback function into listFunc:

`static listFunc(callback){...}`

Instead of returning the list just invoke the callback:

`callback(funclist);`